# Association error in a namespace using Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, namespaces, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

In 'ROOT_RAILS/models/users/account.rb' I have

```
has_one :profile,
  :primary_key => "app_profile_id",
  :foreign_key => "id",
  :dependent => :destroy
```

In 'ROOT_RAILS/models/apps/profile.rb' I have

```
belongs_to :user,
  :primary_key => "id",
  :foreign_key => "app_profile_id"
```

In 'ROOT_RAILS/config/routes.rb' I have

```
namespace "users" do
  resources :accounts
end

namespace "app" do
  resources :profiles
end
```

When I try to access @account.profile (@account is an account ActiveRecord), for example in a '.html.erb' file, I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant Users::Account::Profile
```

**What/where is the problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of headache I found the solution:

```
has_one :profile,
:class_name => "Apps::Profile",
:primary_key => "app_profile_id", 
:foreign_key => "id",
:dependent => :destroy
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should achieve what you're trying to do:

routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  resource :profile
end
```

accounts.rb:

```
has_one :profile, :primary_key => "app_profile_id",
                  :dependent => :destroy
```

profile.rb:

```
belongs_to :user,
           :foreign_key => "app_profile_id"
```

Make sure the profiles table contains a column for the foreign key too.

Comment: I tryed ':foreign_key => "id"' instead of ":foreign_key => "app_profile_id"" so that I make sure I have the foreign key in the profiles table. Anyway it doesn't work... maybe it happens because 'account.rb' and 'profile.rb' are rispectively in '/models/users' and 'models/apps' subfolders. Could this be the problem?